# How can I add two lists having different dimensions in python?

Tags: python, numpy, random, integer, numbers

I have a sorted list of points of intersections `(x, y)` as shown in the list below, named as `coordinates`

```
coordinates =[(66, 66), (132, 66), (199, 66), (266, 66), (333, 66), (399, 66), (466, 66), (533, 66)]
```

I have also an array with errors defined as `Error = [10, 32, 12, 43, 56, 23, 21,11]`

Assuming they're of the same length, is it possible to add every element from the `Error array` such that the output for the coordinates should be as follows

```
new_coordinates = [(66+10, 66+10), (132+32, 66+32), (199+12, 66+12), ..., (533+11, 66+11)]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a one-liner -

```
fixed_coordinates = [tuple(map(lambda x: x+e, cc)) for cc, e in zip(coordinates, Error)]
```

Note that this solution does not assume a specific length of the coordinates, and will work with 3-dimensional (or more) just as well.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do it using list comprehension and `zip()`:

```
new_cordinates = [(x[0]+y, x[1]+y) for (x,y) in zip(coordinates, Error)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple and easy to understand solution:

```
coordinates = [(66, 66), (132, 66), (199, 66), (266, 66),
               (333, 66), (399, 66), (466, 66), (533, 66)]
errors = [10, 32, 12, 43, 56, 23, 21, 11]

output = [(x + e, y + e) for (x, y), e in zip(coordinates, errors)]

print(output)
```

Output:

```
[(76, 76), (164, 98), (211, 78), (309, 109), (389, 122), (422, 89), (487, 87), (544, 77)]
```

What is [zip()](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_zip.asp)?